# Alfresco Solr Querying for Contents

Tags: java, solr, alfresco, alfresco-share

We are working on Integrating a search application[Custom Java aplication] with Alfresco Solr. This application will have to provide users to search against contents indexed by Alfresco Solr.

Question:

- Can we copy the Solr Index on to another Solr core and use the app against the new core.

  Or
- Can we query directly against the solr services directly in Java?

Any references to WIKI or source code for either option is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think there is any issue if you directly read solr indexes created by alfresco.

You can normally find solr indexes of alfresco under
/alf_data

You can refer these articles to get more idea on how alfresco use solr

[Solr in alfresco](http://www.ixxus.com/blog/2012/06/getting-going-solr-alfresco-4)

[Alfresco and solr](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Alfresco_And_SOLR)